# How to export a Makefile from a Visual Studio 2015 C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, makefile

I googled a lot and saw some old posts that it was possible till VS 2008?

But now i can't find the option "export makefile" anymore..

Is there now another way to do this?

Comment: I think "Export Makefile" option was removed after `VS 6.0`. Hence, one can assume that this option was not available even in `VS 2008`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I googled, too, with the same result: There really seems to be *no way* to create a Makefile from a given VS 2015 solution. The closest I got was [MakeItSo](https://code.google.com/p/make-it-so/). It supports VS 2010 but is open source, so maybe you can adapt it to your needs.

My recommendation is using [CMake](https://cmake.org/). Yes, you will have to invest some effort to getting used to it and to convert the project definitions. But managing CMake definitions is much easier than clicking through solution and project property dialogs.

And then you get your Makefile is a nice side effect.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [cmakeconverter](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcproj2cmake/files/) - It doesn't generate Makefiles, but CMakeLists could be considered a superset.